# R group by substring

Tags: r, string, substring

Sample data

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
              name = c("blue", "green", "red", "read", "HUE"),
              WANT = c("ue", "re", "re", "re", "ue"))
```

To explain. If 'name' contains "ue", then WANT = "ue" and if 'name' contains 're' then WANT = "re". Capitalization does not matter.

This is my attempt:

```
    df$attempt <- NA
df$attempt[substr(df$name) == "ue"] <- "ue"
df$attempt[substr(df$name) == "re"] <- "re"
```

Comment: What about the case with no "ue" or "re"? And what about the case when "ue" and "re" both exist?

Comment: if it does not contain "ue" or "re" then group = NA. If it has both [which it should not] then which ever happens first. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `stringr` (part of the `tidyverse`).

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(attempt = str_extract(name, pattern = regex("ue|re", ignore_case = TRUE)),
         attempt = str_to_lower(attempt))
data2
#   id  name WANT attempt
# 1  1  blue   ue      ue
# 2  2 green   re      re
# 3  3   red   re      re
# 4  4  read   re      re
# 5  5   HUE   ue      ue
```

**DATA**

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
              name = c("blue", "green", "red", "read", "HUE"),
              WANT = c("ue", "re", "re", "re", "ue"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a couple of versions

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  name = c("blue", "green", "red", "read", "HUE"))


#base r version
data$want <- ifelse(grepl("ue", data$name, ignore.case = T), "ue",
                    ifelse(grepl("re", data$name, ignore.case = T), "re",
                           NA))
#tidyverse version
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(want = ifelse(grepl("ue", name, ignore.case = T), "ue",
                       ifelse(grepl("re", name, ignore.case = T), "re",
                              NA)))
```

Comment: thanks so much. lastly, say i have 10+ categories. i tried "ifelse" but that does not seem to work. is there another way to present 10+ ifelse statements?

Comment: @bvowe You can use `case_when` from `dplyr` rather than `ifelse`, but `str_extract` from my solution may make more sense if there are 10+ strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ifelse` and `mutate`. `grepl("ue",name,ignore.case = T)` checks if ue or UE exists. Same logic applies to `[re]`

```
library(dplyr)

    data = data%>%
  mutate(Attempt = ifelse(grepl("ue",name,ignore.case = T),"ue",
                          ifelse(grepl("re",name,ignore.case = T),"re",NA)))
```

Comment: that made all of the 'Attempt' variables 'ue'

Comment: Use `ignore.case = TRUE` for `grepl` rather than including both upper and lower case patterns.

Answer (score 0):

With `purrr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(group = map2_chr(WANT, name, ~ .x[grepl(.x, .y, ignore.case = TRUE)]))
```

**Output:**

```
  id  name WANT group
1  1  blue   ue    ue
2  2 green   re    re
3  3   red   re    re
4  4  read   re    re
5  5   HUE   hu    hu
```

**Data:**

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   name = c("blue", "green", "red", "read", "HUE"),
                   WANT = c("ue", "re", "re", "re", "hu"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: The `WANT` column may not be there.